# How to process content while updating associative map in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, state

How would one implement a transformation in Haskell that is straightforward in imperative language because it can easily update map and its contents?

```
while( line = next()) {
  Data d = parse(line);
  if( map.get(d.key) == null) map.put(d.info);
  else map.get(d.key).update(d.info);
}

for(d : map.values) print d.computeResult()
```

To give (oversimplified) concrete example, input would contain lines that need to be correlated by some rule. Here, a program should detect that values under key 'k' are being added, updated but ultimately removed and should not appear in output.

```
[time] ADD key=k, value1=V1
[time] ADD key=k, value2=V2
[time] ADD key=k, value1=ABC
[time] [...]
[time] DEL key=k
[time] ADD key=k2, value1=V1
```

Should I consider using lenses, state monad, sort the data by key (if possible) or something else? Which would be cleanest way (with least boilerplatte) to implement this? I'm wondering whether such Haskell scripts could be easier to maintain than awk/sed/grep/xmlstartlet soup for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`insert :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a` from `Data.Map` does exactly what you want.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

addLines :: [String] -> M.Map Int String
addLines = foldr (uncurry M.insert) M.empty . parseLines
    where parseLines :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
          parseLines = zip [1..]
```

`addLines` takes a list of lines to store, an returns a `Map` with line numbers as keys for the lines. If you just slurped a bunch of text into a `String`, use `lines :: String -> [String]` to break it into lines.

As suggested by Gabriel in the comments, a better way to convert a list of lines to a `Map` is

```
addLines = M.fromList . zip [1..]
```

Note: the first function allows you to pass in an initial `Map` instead of `M.empty`, but using `M.union` to combine `Map`s with the second function will probably be faster.

Comment: Even better, use `Data.Map.fromList` (which should be faster, too).

Comment: ... and if you want to also add in another map, use `Data.Map.union`.